# Google Sheet Dynamic Sheet Range: Offset and Index and Indirect

Tags: google-sheets

I have a chart that references a separate sheet. So the source for the chart is a range like this `'Daily'!A1:EL14`

The source sheet grows daily by 1 column. I want the chart to update dynamically every day after the new column is added. I believe that requires the use of `INDIRECT`

I can get values from a column, but can't get the actual CELL REFERENCE or a string like "EL14".

Here's functions that return values:

NUM_COLUMNS

`= countif('Daily'!A1:ZZ1, "<>")`

VALUE OF LAST COLUMN IN ROW 1

`= OFFSET(
    'Daily LT 1sec'!A1,
    0,
    (countif('Daily'!A1:ZZ1, "<>")-1)
)`

VALUE OF LASTROW : LASTCOLUMN

`= OFFSET(
    'Daily LT 1sec'!A1,
    (countif('Daily LT 1sec'!A1:A100, "<>")-1),
    (countif('Daily'!A1:ZZ1, "<>")-1)
)`

Can someone explain to me how I would use INDIRECT to actually get a create a valid cell range to use in the chart definition?

Answer (score 0):

You may use extra columns for source range. The empty cells won't affect the chart.

In my sample I used range A1:B508, but actual data is in range A1:AB8:
[image]

---

I've tried to use formula as chart source, but that didn't work. I found some more info here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/d08hJbjfaLI/HqACX_7zA3MJ